# Angular Javascript export CSV. Is there a way specify the file extension consistently in Mac and Windows

Tags: javascript, angularjs, windows, macos, csv

I have the following line of code:

`window.location.href = "data:text/csv;base64," + csvdata`

that set to export csv data. it works on Mac with the extension "csv", but on windows it doesn't recognize as csv file. is there a way to specify the file extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use navigator.msSaveBlob in IE, and .download for others.

```
 var blob = new Blob([csvdata], {
    type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8;"
  });
  var fileName = 'data.csv';

  if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
  } else {
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    downloadLink.download = fileName;

    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
  }
```